# Where do I put the storefront.yaml for custom settings?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to use CSRF in ajax mode - [Use CSRF protection](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/use-csrf-protection#exclude-controller-action-from-csrf-checks)

Currently I edited the storefront.yaml in vendor/shopware folder, but that shouldn't be right? For config changes, I should create a new .yaml file, but where do I put it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should go to `config/packages/storefront.yaml`

EDIT: Better `z-shopware.yaml`
See comments.

Comment: According to the docs https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/reverse-http-cache#configure-shopware `config/packages/storefront.yaml` is right.

Comment: Please note this file is overwritten when you update Shopware via web installer. A workaround is to create `config/packages/z-shopware.yaml` and put your modifications there.